# Doesn't work PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I try to use following PowerShell script in iLoveSharePoint.PowerEventReceiver

```
function ItemAdding
{
    $url = 'http://win-4cc5e89pifo:1234/docs/'
    $web = Get-SPWeb -webUrl $url
    $list = $web.Lists['CodeBehind']

    foreach ($item in $list)
    {
        if ($item.Title -eq $properties.AfterProperties["Title"])
        {
            $properties.Status = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverStatus]::CancelWithRedirectUrl

            $properties.RedirectUrl = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUrlUtility]::CombineUrl($properties.Web.Url,"/SitePages/step1.aspx?p=1")

            break
        }   
    }
}
```

Where is an error?

Comment: It would help a lot if you told us what "doesn't work" and what error message you are getting.

Comment: I could'n becase iLoveSharepoint don't give debug information. But $list.length is empty

Comment: Did you try like I suggested?

Comment: Try `Set-PSDebug -strict` before running your script.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no named parameter `-webUrl` for the `Get-SPWeb` Cmdlet.

Try

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
```

in your script instead.

Also check if `$web` isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

try this
`CombineUrl($web.Url,`
or

```
$httpContext.Response.Redirect("somewhere/to/go",$true);
```